# What do I do if I have killed Trevor before starting the Real Estate mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I forgot to do the real estate mission, and now can't, as I have killed Trevor. This also means I can't buy a house.

I have tried calling Josh, with Franklin, but he never picks up.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

No, when you choose to kill Trevor, you **cannot** start the real estate mission.

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What is your source on this?